# Is there a way to use the UnityEngine.UI with SteamVR and the Vive?

Tags: unity, ui-design, steam, virtual-reality

I recently got into developing VR games using the Vive as my standard platform. Now I would like to design some UnityEngine.UI elements that would be interactable via the built in pointer scripts that come with the SteamVR module from the Unity Asset Store.  However, I can't seem to find any kind of built in method for allowing interaction between the pointers and buttons, scroll bars, etc.  I have also been unable to write anything myself that would do the trick, it's almost as if the Unity UI is just not designed to interact in a VR environment at all.  Does anyone have a method for using the UnityEngine.UI in a VR environment?  If so, can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: https://github.com/VREALITY/ViveUGUIModule

It is doable without this. I'm pretty sure I've just used a default UI Button though (can't check right now).

Comment: Confirmed!  This works!